# How to show all child products of bundle product in cart page in magento

Tags: php, magento, bundle

I want to display all child products of Bundle product in magento.Now only one child product is displaying everywhere.

Thanks 
in Advance

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 4):

```
$bundled_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_BUNDLED_PRODUCT_ID);
$selectionCollection = $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
    $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled_product), $bundled_product
);
$bundled_items = array();
foreach($selectionCollection as $option)
{
    $bundled_items[] = $option->product_id;
}
print_r($bundled_items);
```